# How can convert inputstream to InputStreamsource or Datasource to attach in Spring JavaMail

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail, inputstream, sftp, jsch

I am getting inputstream from the Jsch channelSFTP like below.

```
   ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
   InputStream input = channelsftp.get(unixPath); // unixPath is path to my file which is on SFTP server
```

I have to attach the file in the `unixPath` in the Spring JavaMail attachment. But when I see API of Spring JavaMail [`addAttachment()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#addAttachment%28java.lang.String,%20javax.activation.DataSource%29) method it takes only `InputStreamSource` or `Datasource`.
My problem is I am not able to get the `InputStreamSource` or `Datasource` from the inputStream which I am getting form SFTP channel.

How Can I get `InputStreamSource` or `Datasource` from the above `InputStream`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From the documentation, [`InputStreamSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamSource.html) is an interface.  One of its implementations is [`InputStreamResource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html), which has a constructor that takes in an `InputStream`.  [Here is the JavaDoc for it](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html#InputStreamResource%28java.io.InputStream%29).

You should be able to setup your call as such:

```
addAttachment("Not porn", new InputStreamResource(inputStream));
```

Comment: For me exactly  message.addAttachment("somefile name",new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(channelSftp.get(unixPath)))); is working.Thanks anyway for the idea.

Comment: Note that this method does not allow for an `inputStream` that is already open.

Comment: up for that awesome filename "not porn"

Comment: @SRy the method you showed worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I host a **Spring Boot application in Docker** on my VPS. This code will work on a local system whilst developing in an IDE **as well as if the .JAR-file is wrapped in a Docker image**:

Example case:

I like to get a PDF. The PDf document is located at `static/docs/not-a-porn.PDF`.

1.) Wire the class `ResourceLoader`.

```java
private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

public MyService(@Autowired ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {  
    this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
}
```

2.) Create a resource by `pathOfAttachment` (`String`).

```java
String pathOfAttachment = "classpath:static/docs/not-a-porn.PDF"
Resource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource(pathOfAttachment);
```

`Resource` is an interface that extends `InputStreamSource` as you can see in the documentation:

`public interface Resource extends InputStreamSource`

Source: `org.springframework.core.io` [Link to documentation (click here)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html)